# Why won't this ajax run during facebook login?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-login

I'm running a special facebook login on my site where, when a use clicks it, the following must occur:

- Connect with FB
- If facebook ID already recognized in user database, do XXX
- If facebook ID not recognized, do YYY

For some reason, I cannot get the ajax query that checks the facebook ID to work properly.  I've spent several hours now on this and still no luck (starting to feel like a real timesink)...  Even if I set the query to only return 0 (eg, change the second echo to also be 'echo 0'), it doesn't (unless I strip the entire function down to literally just 'echo 0'). Any thoughts on why this might be happening?  Code below:

ajax query called in the function (with input of var fbid):

```
<?php
    // configuration
    require("../html/includes/config.php"); 

    // connect to server
    $connect = mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    $fbid = $_POST["fbid"];

    $fbidcheck = query('SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE fbid = ?', $_POST["fbid"]);
    if (isset($fbidcheck[0]["fbid"]))
        echo 0;
    else
        echo 1;
?>
```

JS function called when someone clicks the login button:

```
// FB login function
function fblogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {

            // Here, I want to test if the facebook ID is already in the table

            var fbid = response.authResponse.userID;
            $.post("check_fbid.php", {'fbid': fbid}, function(result)
            {    
               if(result == 0)
               {
                    // login in the user
                    // use fbid to call session, etc. for login
                    location.reload();
                    return true;
               }
               else
               {
                    // open new box on page to let user register
                    openRegisterBox();
                    return false;
               }
           });
        } else {
            // Login was cancelled or failed
            return false;
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}
```

Again, I've tracked the problem down to the ajax query not running properly (I've even tried to re-create it a few times).  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your jquery code looks like it should work and if it works when your PHP is just an echo 0 statement then maybe your returning more than just a 1 or 0 in your PHP.  Have you looked to see what exactly your PHP script returns?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to just spit directly the output from ajax (always seem to need to print something and get a result).  However, I know that what you describe is not the issue as I have tried taking the exact php code from above and setting it to else echo 0 (so in both cases it should echo 0), and still the function would execute as if 0 was NOT returned.  It's weird to me, I'm wondering if it has something to do with the facebook element

Comment: I cannot say for sure without knowing what your PHP file is really returning.

I just implemented your code with the Facebook JS SDK and it worked just fine.  I am wondering if your PHP is displaying a warning or error.  Try commenting out the DB code and return a 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it using your code and it worked just fine.
Here is everything expect for the PHP code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function fblogin() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        var fbid = response.authResponse.userID;
                        $.post("http://johnhiott.com/play/fbid.php", {'fbid': fbid}, function(result){    
                            if(result == 0){
                                alert("in");
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                alert("no");
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }, {scope: 'email'});
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // Additional JS functions here
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '284563394889810', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//WWW.JOHNHIOTT.COM/play/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional init code here

      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    </script>


    </body>

    <a href="#" onClick="fblogin()">hi</a>
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: So kind of strange, it happened to start working although I never figured out what the issue was...  Maybe things somehow had gotten cached? (which doesn't really make sense since visible updates to the page were appearing...)

Comment: @John: Can you please tell me in which line jquery call is taking place? I just tried to run your code by taking facebool button `<div id="LoginButton">
    <div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();" size="medium" scope="<?php echo $fbPermissions; ?>">Connect With Facebook</div>
    </div>` then it reloads the page two times!